# Why is there selective deletion of comments challenging the moderators, especially one moderator

Tags: discussion

[image]

Clearly, there was a conversation between me and the moderator. All comments of mine challenging the moderator have been conveniently deleted by the moderator(s). Only their comments have been retained evidently to showcase their own virtue in this transaction. Without access to the entire conversation, it is impossible to understand that my comments were much more generalised about site rules and mod practices and were not limited to the post in question.

1. What gives them the right to do so?
2. Why and HOW are they still occupying the mantle of moderator?

Note: I am not questioning the deletion of the post in the picture. Just the selective and utterly biased actions of the moderator(s). Many of my comments on several questions have been deleted, especially those that questioned this moderator.

Jeez, this site has not changed an ounce since I took a break from posting. Same old, different day.

Comment: this moderator has an "amen-corner" that supports him unconditionally and allows him to inflate his reputation to infinity with upvotes.  This clique has rendered this site toxic - nothing but the cleansing forces of capitalism can stop them.  If they stand in the way of ad-revenue, they will be swept away.

Comment: You did not post any comments on that post.  I was replying in the comments to a flag you had raised on that post.

Comment: @SK We don't depend on ad revenue anyway.

Comment: if that is the case, I misspoke. Regardless, it is subversive to not quote the original Q which is invisible to all while providing an answer and defence that is visible to all.  As for deletion of several other comments on other Q's and A's, my question stands.  @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: For the record, it's not visible to all; deleted answers are only visible to users with 2000 reputation or more, and we didn't have many (if any) users with that high a reputation back then.  That message was just intended for you to read, so there was no need to quote your flag.  But regardless, here is your flag: "The other answers don't quote scripture or cite sources. This is starting to look like targeting." And I explained why I deleted your answer but not the others.

Comment: That is still several users seeing your answer and zero users seeing my Q. Posting my Q here is eyewash but it is better than nothing. I had to make a flag to communicate with you because you deleted the answer and I could not add a comment. I do remember that this was part of several Q's and comments on the topic - which is why I mentioned targeting in this Q without preamble. The preamble had been given in other comments/notes/flags earlier.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is more of a complaint rather than a question that can be answered.

For example "Why is there..?" can only be answered by that moderator who was involved.

For this

> What gives them the right to do so?

the answer is because he is a moderator he can delete as he is empowered to do so. Whether fair or unfair another issue.

> Why and HOW are they still occupying the mantle of moderator?

I mean how can one answer this.. it can sound a bit harsh but is this the first time you have encountered a moderator whose workings have been unfair? I have seen many such moderators in other forums.

But, **the problem definitely exists** and i can say that from my personal experience.

Keeping exactly this issue in mind i had posted earlier this question - [Can comments deleted by one moderator be restored by another?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/941/can-comments-deleted-by-one-moderator-be-restored-by-another)

So, from the answer it is clear, the other moderators can see all those deleted comments. If they also feel that deletion was unfair then they can restore the comments.

Or, if you yourself notice you can also raise the issue in the chatroom called "Moderation". The other moderators can then look into it.

Since, the mods are the only persons who can see the deleted comments, consulting them first (before posting here) makes sense. If the other mods also say that the deletion was fair according to them too, then of course posting here is the solution.

But, the real problem here is that we can't really know when our comments are getting deleted. So, it is fairly cumbersome for us to keep a track of the situation (by going to the "all action" tab we can check but that's exactly how it is cumbersome).

Here, i have just given a practical solution for the problem. IMO, situation is not that bad now, like how it was previously, when there was only one decision-making mod. As i have seen one mod (of the current group) **undoing what was done by another on several occasions. So, we can expect fair moderation now.**

Comment: 'raise the issue in the chatroom called "Moderation". The other moderators can then look into it.' - what exactly does 'look into it' mean?99% of the time if you contest a mod action, it won't be reversed. Why bother complaining? If you complain on meta, at least other users are alerted to the issue and know what's going on.

Comment: In this case talking to the other mods first makes lots of sense.. once the comment is gone u can't see it, neither can any other users, only the mods can..so just ask the other mods what do u think? if they say Ok i agree with u, then the comment is restored within no time.. If u post here then people will ask what was the comment like? and only the mods can help u regarding this... if it was the case of deletion of answers then many users including may be the OP can also see it..so discussion can start without any involvement of the mods..but not possible in case of comments..@sv.

Comment: @sv. I am not saying do not post here.. if the other mods say no the deletion was fair, then u can come and post here.. to see what others have to say on the issue..i personally never like discussing in chatrooms like u have said and for the same reasons u have mentioned.. see what i have written [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/when-we-have-complaints-against-moderation-is-raising-a-meta-the-only-or-recomme)..

Comment: once for either moving comments to chat or deletion which i considered as unfair i had to threaten a mod like this " Either undo ur move or else i will take this to meta" and it worked..: the comments were restored.. so in case of deletion of comments first talking to the other mods makes sense.. also it is not that mods have never ever undone what other mods have done.. i bear testimony that one mod has undone what another mod has done on more than one occasion.. so such complaints can and do work.. and if they don't then of course a meta post is always an option @sv.